# Ktor project from command line in Linux

Tags: linux, ktor

As mentioned in [ktor cli](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-cli) website, I'm trying to install it in my Linux machine. But I ended up with below error.

> error: cannot install "ktor": persistent network error: Post
> https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup
> api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

Is it possible to install Ktor on Linux and how to create and run a project?

Comment: I put snap install --beta --classic ktor on my terminal with sudo access, yes before that I have installed snap too
after 
Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap ktor

ktor (beta) 2.0.0-eap-3 from Ktor (ololoshechkin) installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ktor cli explicitly supports linux and installation through snap

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-cli

From that link you can install and create a project with

```
snap install --beta --classic ktor
```

and

```
ktor generate ktor-sample
```

respectively.

Your problem looks like it is related to your network's DNS and is an unrelated problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to ping first

> ping api.snapcraft.io

**64 bytes from api.snapcraft.io (185.xxx.xxx.xx): icmp_seq=189 ttl=53 time=23.6 ms**

maybe your network issue

**set up your proxy**

> sudo snap unset system proxy.http
>
> sudo snap unset system proxy.https
>
> sudo systemctl restart snapd

maybe your **network interface card driver** is not **steady**
try to connect **apt source**

or **use external tethering network for testing purpose**

after that hit this command again

> snap install --beta --classic ktor